# Using supplier with largest margin using PHP logic

Tags: php

I have the following values from a database call that I want to apply some logic to. I thought I could originally use PHP's `max` however this doesn't appear to be the case.

I have three suppliers of a product. They might not all stock the item I am displaying, and they all offer a different margin, on a product by product basis though, so that is why I can't just say generally supplier 1 is better than supplier 2 etc.

```
$supplier1Live = 1
$supplier2Live = 1
$supplier3Live = 0

$marginSupplier1 = 20
$marginSupplier2 = 40
$martinSupplier3 = 50
```

In this example I would want to use Supplier 2 as they stock the product `supplier2Live = 1` and also have the better margin than the other supplier who stocks the product (supplier1)

My mind however is drawing a complete blank in how to code this?

I thought I could add it to an array giving:

```
$array = array(
    "supplier1" => array(
         "live" => 1,
         "margin" => 20
     ),
     "supplier2" => array(
         "live" => 1,
         "margin" => 40
     ),
     "supplier3" => array(
         "live" => 0,
         "margin" => 50
     )
);
```

And run something on that, but not sure what to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter the array using [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) (filter by live==1), and then find the maximum out of the resultant array (maximum on the "margin" value)

Like this, if I understand correctly

```
$array = array(
    "supplier1" => array(
        "live" => 1,
        "margin" => 20
    ),
    "supplier2" => array(
        "live" => 1,
        "margin" => 40
    ),
    "supplier3" => array(
        "live" => 0,
        "margin" => 50
    )
);
$res = array_filter($array,function($v){return $v["live"];});
$supplier = array_reduce($res, function($a, $b){
       return $a["margin"]>$b["margin"]?$a:$b;
});
print_r($supplier);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$best_supplier = null;
$best_supplier_margin = null;
foreach($array as $name => $supplier) {
    if($supplier['live']) {
        if($supplier['margin'] > $best_supplier_margin || is_null($best_supplier_margin)) {
            $best_supplier = $name;
            $best_supplier_margin = $supplier['margin'];
        }
    }
}

if(is_null($best_supplier)) throw new Exception('No suppliers are live!');

echo $best_supplier;
```

Answer (score 0):

So you basically want to find the `max` of `supplierXLive * marginSupplierX`?

Comment: No, I want to find the name (supplierx) of the one who has the biggest margin but also has live = 1

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement a custom compare function and provide it to PHPs [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function